# sklearn.lda.LDA Parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

From the sklearn.lda.LDA Parameters , does anyone could explain what are these parameters and it's best use:

1. shrinkage
2. priors
3. store_covariance
4. tol